# How to write a Regex pattern for the following string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I am trying to write a Regex pattern to modify the caption of my datagridview.
I need to remove following characters from each string:
space
[
]
*
#
?
/
\
@
(
)
.
""
''
I am super confused and I need your help in defining the patter of the Regex in C#. This is my sample code:

```
DataTable d_new = d;
for (int i = 0; i < d.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string t = d.Columns[i].Caption;
    string regex = "\\s+"; // this needs to Be expanded
    string t_new = Regex.Replace(t, regex, "_");
    d.Columns[i].Caption = t_new;
}
```

Comment: Do you *really* need a regex for that? Why don't you simply use the `Remove` method?

Comment: *[what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)*

Comment: @Andre, sorry I don't know the replace method, I searched the internet and found Regex thats why I am using it and I know it might not be efficient.

Comment: @Amir if all you need is to remove a set of given characters from a string, `Remove` is way better than a regex.

Comment: @ zzzzBov you can see my code thats why I tried so far with some combination of Regex that it didn't work

Comment: @Amir, I don't see any of the regex that you've tried, beyond the `"\\s+"` string. So, I'm going to ask again, **what have you tried**?

Comment: **zzzzBov he hasn't tried because that is his question he doesn't know how to setup the regex**.  Please get off his case.

Comment: @AndreCalil did you mean `Remove` or `Replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var invalidChars = new HashSet<char>(@"[]*#?/\@()");
var output = new string( input.Where(c => !invalidChars.Contains(c)).ToArray() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This would match what you want, just replace with an empty string or what you want.

```
[ \[\]*#?/\\@()."']
```

But in this case an regex is a bit overkill, you could just use `Remove`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 string regex = "[\[\]*#?\/\\@()."']";
```